# Powershell Script Creating Registry Detection Method in DeploymentType

Tags: powershell, sccm

So I have Script to Create an Application in SCCM and a Script to Create the DeploymentType.
in the DeploymentType, I am Creating a Detection Method that uses the Registry.

```
$clause1 = New-CMDetectionClauseRegistryKeyValue -Hive LocalMachine -KeyName "SOFTWARE\Folder1\Folrder2\$DepName" -ValueName "some_Value" -PropertyType String -ExpressionOperator IsEquals -ExpectedValue $DepNummer -Value

    Add-CMScriptDeploymentType -ApplicationName $DepName -DeploymentTypeName $DepTypeName -ContentLocation $DepContent -InstallCommand $DepInst -UninstallCommand $DepUninst -AddDetectionClause $Clause1 -EstimatedRuntimeMins $DepMaxRun -MaximumRuntimeMins $DepMinRun -LogonRequirementType WhetherOrNotUserLoggedOn -UserInteractionMode Hidden -InstallationBehaviorType InstallForSystem -AddRequirement $oDTRule
```

The Script works so far but I have one small issue. 
if you look at a Detection Method by Registry there is the Checkbox

**“This registry key is associated with a 32-bit application on 64-bit systems”**
I know for what it is but I just can't figure out what I have to do to Create the DM without this box being checked.

I pulled the info about the DeploymenType with Get-CMDeploymentType. I found the parts für the DM but no hint about this Checkbox.

```
<EnhancedDetectionMethod>
    <Settings xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/SystemCenterConfigurationManager/2009/AppMgmtDigest\">
        <SimpleSetting xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/SystemsCenterConfigurationManager/2009/07/10/DesiredConfiguration\" LogicalName=\"RegSetting_8277224f-cd13-48b8-8a94-efbe3b67d5ea\" DataType=\"String\">
            <Annotation xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/SystemsCenterConfigurationManager/2009/06/14/Rules\">
                <DisplayName Text=\"\"/>
                <Description Text=\"\"/>
            </Annotation>
            <RegistryDiscoverySource Hive=\"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\" Depth=\"Base\" Is64Bit=\"true\" CreateMissingPath=\"true\">
                <Key>SOFTWARE\\Folder1\\Folder2\\Stuff</Key>
                <ValueName>some_Value</ValueName>
            </RegistryDiscoverySource>
        </SimpleSetting>
    </Settings>
    <Rule xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/SystemsCenterConfigurationManager/2009/06/14/Rules\" id=\"ScopeId_F7D7B005-5475-42F3-8D53-C6F2B0DA1B17/DeploymentType_1dae9225-e8ee-4923-b38f-2bdcf3bd656d\" Severity=\"Informational\" NonCompliantWhenSettingIsNotFound=\"false\">
        <Annotation>
            <DisplayName Text=\"\"/>
            <Description Text=\"\"/>
        </Annotation>
        <Expression>
            <Operator>Equals</Operator>
            <Operands>
                <SettingReference AuthoringScopeId=\"ScopeId_F7D7B005-5475-42F3-8D53-C6F2B0DA1B17\" LogicalName=\"Application_6f616284-4cb8-423b-94a5-20d6e5f687fd\" Version=\"8\" DataType=\"String\" SettingLogicalName=\"RegSetting_8277224f-cd13-48b8-8a94-efbe3b67d5ea\" SettingSourceType=\"Registry\" Method=\"Value\" Changeable=\"false\"/>
                <ConstantValue Value=\"some_Value\" DataType=\"String\"/>
            </Operands>
        </Expression>
    </Rule>
</EnhancedDetectionMethod>
```

has anyone an idea.

thx in advanced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so never asume anything.

as i said and you can see above i pulled the info via get-CMDeploymentType and looked at it once with Checkbox checked and once when i manualy set it unchecked.

But something trolled me.

```
<RegistryDiscoverySource Hive=\"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\" Depth=\"Base\" Is64Bit=\"true\" CreateMissingPath=\"true\">
```

The Magic is in the Is64Bit="\true\" part

i am sure that after changing it manualy in SCCM this was still true so i did not look into the switch -is64Bit

Well someone on the TechNet Forum said i should look into it again and i did. i put it into the script and oh wonder it works.

```
New-CMDetectionClauseRegistryKeyValue -Hive LocalMachine -KeyName "SOFTWARE\Folder1\Folrder2\$DepName" -Is64Bit -ValueName "some_Value" -PropertyType String -ExpressionOperator IsEquals -ExpectedValue $DepNummer -Value
```

This is the Version so the Checkbox is not checked.

regards